# Content Security Policy on spotify embed only safari

Tags: html, security, drupal

On a Drupal website im having issues with a spotify embed that shows podcasts. It gives me this error in the developers console.

> Refused to load https://embed-standalone.spotify.com/embed/episode/6i0qePIZY5RdHM2p42WpDy because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

I have tried adding a meta content security policy, but with no succes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Content-Security-Policy: frame-src <source>`

And it would be helpful if you posted your code